# Can app-routing.module.ts has 2 path with :/id

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I trying to open maindetail and childdetails page with :/id. But when I run it on localhost, there is no card that i wanted in maindetail page.

What I am trying to do is, i can click the name “aniq” in dashboard (image 1)and shows the child detail page. But the child detail page is not showing the card i wanted (image 2). However when I try to reenter the link localhost:8100/maindetal (image 3) the card is showing. I dont know what is wrong. Can anyone help me, thanks.

this is my app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginPageModule' },
  { path: 'register', loadChildren: './register/register.module#RegisterPageModule' },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '', loadChildren: './pages/tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule' },
   { path: 'maindetail', loadChildren: './pages/maindetail/maindetail.module#MaindetailPageModule' },
  { path: 'maindetail/:id', loadChildren: './pages/maindetail/maindetail.module#MaindetailPageModule' },
  { path: 'childdetails', loadChildren: './pages/childdetails/childdetails.module#ChilddetailsPageModule' },
  { path: 'childdetails/:id', loadChildren: './pages/childdetails/childdetails.module#ChilddetailsPageModule' },
];
```

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5ac8.jpg)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dv9L0.jpg)
[image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCVcE.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can have multiple routes with parameters in Angular. You can even have multiple parameters in the same route!

However, usually when using lazy-loading modules you will have another routing module inside that lazy-loading module. I know the word "module" gets thrown around a lot so I'll break it down with an example that should help hopefully.

`app-routing.module.ts`

Let's focus on just the child details module. Below we only have one route for `/childdetails`

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'childdetails', loadChildren: 
 './pages/childdetails/childdetails.module#ChilddetailsPageModule' },
];
```

But, we want to get the id which will be passed in as a route param. So we create a file called `childdetails-routing.module.ts` wherever our module is. Inside that file we'll have almost the exact same setup as I'll show below:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: ':id', component: yourChildDetailComponent },
];
```

You may want to reference the exact documentation to get the details exactly right https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules#configure-the-feature-modules-routes

Comment: Thank you for answering this, so I just need to create childdetails-routing.module.ts and discard this line  
**{ path: 'childdetails', loadChildren: './pages/childdetails/childdetails.module#ChilddetailsPageModule' },
 { path: 'childdetails/:id', loadChildren: './pages/childdetails/childdetails.module#ChilddetailsPageModule' },'**
 in app-routing.module.ts
Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: Almost, you need to get rid of one of the two references to your mainDetail module in your `app-routing.module.ts` file and then add the `{path: 'id', component: yourChildComponent` to your `childDetailsPage-routing.module.ts` file